# How to solve infinite recursion error in R using installr package?

Tags: r, installation

I've installed `installr` package. The first time I ran the following code, it worked without any error. After, when I run my code, I got this error:

**Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?**

```
if(!require(installr)) {
      install.packages("installr"); require(installr)
} 
updateR()
```

What should I do to solve the problem?